# Build error on React 17 when trying to import a new custom library

Tags: reactjs, build, vite, craco

I'm working with a React 17 frontend with Craco/Webpack. On another repo, I have a library that is using React 17, but with Vite. What is happening is that, when I try to import this library in my main frontend app, it throws this error when I try to build it:

> Attempted import error: 'useInsertionEffect' is not exported from 'react'

Now, I tried with other libraries and this issue is not happening, so my thoughts are that the library is causing problems (maybe misalignment of something?) to the main application.

### Frontend

Craco has this babel.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        runtime: "automatic",
        importSource: "@emotion/react",
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: ["@emotion/babel-plugin"],
};
```

and this webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    clean: true,
    environment: {
      arrowFunction: false,
      bigIntLiteral: false,
      const: false,
      destructuring: false,
      dynamicImport: true,
      forOf: false,
      module: false,
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      path: false,
      assert: false,
      buffer: false,
      fs: false,
      tls: false,
      net: false,
      zlib: false,
      http: false,
      https: false,
      stream: false,
      crypto: false,
    },
  },
};
```

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.9",
    "@casl/ability": "^5.2.2",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.0.3",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.0.3",
    "@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop": "^11.2.0",
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.7",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.163",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.7",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.15.7",
    "@mui/system": "^5.15.7",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.19.3",
    "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^2.1.26",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^7.44.2",
    "@sentry/react": "^7.44.2",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.44.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/animejs": "3.1.7",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.2",
    "animejs": "3.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "concurrently": "^6.0.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.27.0",
    "deep-object-diff": "^1.1.0",
    "detect-browser": "^5.3.0",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^7.1.0",
    "emotion": "^11.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "6.3.10",
    "iban": "^0.0.14",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jotai": "^1.6.5",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.19",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "notistack": "2.0.8",
    "p-retry": "^5.1.1",
    "qs": "^6.11.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-autocomplete": "^1.8.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-clamp-lines": "^3.0.3",
    "react-currency-input-field": "^3.5.1",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.9",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.31.3",
    "react-idle-timer": "^5.3.0",
    "react-inverted-scrollview": "^1.0.7",
    "react-lazyload": "^3.2.0",
    "react-linkify": "^1.0.0-alpha",
    "react-localization": "^1.0.16",
    "react-number-format": "^4.7.3",
    "react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
    "react-qr-code": "^1.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.3",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.9",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "rich-markdown-editor": "^11.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.1.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3",
    "swr": "^0.4.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.5",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "use-context-selector": "^1.3.9",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "validator": "^13.5.2",
    "webpack-retry-chunk-load-plugin": "^3.1.1"
  },
```

### Library

vite config:

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { resolve } from "node:path";
import { RollupOptions } from "rollup";
import {
  AliasOptions,
  BuildOptions,
  ConfigEnv,
  LibraryOptions,
  PluginOption,
  UserConfig,
  defineConfig,
  loadEnv,
} from "vite";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";

function configuration({ mode }: ConfigEnv): UserConfig {
  process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };

  const plugins: PluginOption[] = [
    react(),
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    }),
  ];

  const rollupOptions: RollupOptions = {
    external: ["react", "react-dom"],
    output: {
      globals: {
        react: "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
      },
    },
  };

  const lib: LibraryOptions = {
    entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
    name: process.env.VITE_LIB_NAME || process.env.npm_package_name,
  };

  const build: BuildOptions = {
    lib,
    rollupOptions,
    sourcemap: true,
  };

  const alias: AliasOptions = {
    "@": resolve(__dirname, "src"),
  };

  return {
    plugins,
    build,
    resolve: { alias },
  };
}

export default defineConfig(configuration);
```

dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3"
  },
```

Can anyone help with this issue? Thank you!

I tried multiple approaches, mainly trying to change the vite.config.ts on the library, and its rollup options:

```
  const rollupOptions: RollupOptions = {
    external: ["react", "react-dom"],
    output: {
      globals: {
        react: "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
      },
    },
  };
```

But it doesn't seem to work.